# Unable to install rmagick on mojave

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rvm

Went thru many blogs in stackoverflow inorder to install rmagick but didnt find a solution. Any help is much appreciated.

Tried using uninstalling and reinstalling imagemagick. Flow some links like [Install rmagick](https://blog.francium.tech/installing-rmagick-on-osx-high-sierra-7ea71f57390d)

Here is the output

```
sudo gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick- 
2.16.0/ext/RMagick
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r 
./siteconf20181206-50407-46eq96.rb extconf.rb
checking for xcrun... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... no
checking for presence of MagickWand API (ImageMagick version >= 
6.9.0)... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of 
necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  
You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:104:in ``': No such file or directory - MagickWand-config 
(Errno::ENOENT)
from extconf.rb:104:in `configure_compile_options'
from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
from extconf.rb:548:in `new'
from extconf.rb:548:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log 
which can be found here:

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/rmagick-2.16.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal- 
darwin-18/2.3.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've installed Imagemagick per the instructions in your link, your shell may missing the path to the binaries. You can test by running a console command:

```
which MagickWand-config
```

If it returns a path (likely `/usr/local/bin/MagickWand-config`) your path is probably fine. If it returns `MagickWand-config not found` you should be able to type `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` in your console.

If your path wasn't correct before, after running the export command you can re-run the `which MagickWand-config` command to confirm it's in your path. Then try to `gem install rmagick` again.

I was able to install rmagick on Mojave following the link you posted.

If this did fix your issue you'll also want to add the export command I noted in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zsh_profile` file so that path is prepended in every terminal window (if it's not there already)